# Fill view with IOS camera preview layer

Tags: ios, swift

Working through a tutorial, and I'm trying to make a full screen preview.  Currently, my camera seems very square, and I am fairly confident this might be an aspect fit issue.  The camera seems to hit the right and left bounds.  How can I pin the my preview to the bottom of the nav bar and the bottom of the screen, and the sides?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var previewLayer:CALayer!

    var captureDevice:AVCaptureDevice!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        prepareCamera()
    }

    func prepareCamera(){
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

        if let availableDevices = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .back).devices {
            captureDevice = availableDevices.first
            beginSession()
        }
    }

    func beginSession () {
        do {
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) {
            self.previewLayer = previewLayer
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
            self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame
//ADD CONSTRAINTS HERE

            captureSession.startRunning()

            let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
            dataOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString):NSNumber(value:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]

            dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

            if captureSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput) {
                captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
            }

            captureSession.commitConfiguration()

//            let queue = DispatchQueue(label: com.willkie.captureQueue)
//            dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
        }
    }

    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didDrop sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

[image: why???]

Comment: What happens if you replace `self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame` with `self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds`?

Comment: @nathan it does the same thing.

Comment: I did just look at the regular camera app and the preview layer for that is the same size.

Comment: You gotta set the video gravity of the preview layer to aspect fill. self.previewLayer.videoGravity  = resizeAspectFill

Comment: @pochi Use of unresolved identifier. Looking into the objects it comes from.

Comment: `previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it with **Swift 4** like this:

Don't forget to import AVKit

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video),
        let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) else {return}

    captureSession.addInput(input)
    captureSession.startRunning()

    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    previewLayer.frame = view.frame
    previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

}
```

Comment: I had to `previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill` when moving from a iPhone6 to iPhone11 in a Xamarin Forms app. Otherwise the view would be in the safe area on iPhone11. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I think probably changing your this particular line should work -

```
self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame
```

to

```
self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds
```

Also you should add your sublayer  only after you have adjusted the frame in the above code. Right now you have added before.

```
self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
```

And you also need to add gravity

```
previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
```

If it still doesn't work, add a custom view to your viewcontroller and set it to the size on which you want to show the camera preview and then you can use this -

```
self.previewLayer.frame = self.customViewOutlet.layer.bounds
```

Comment: This line: `previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill` solves the issue for me.

Comment: This line: self.previewLayer.frame = self.customViewOutlet.layer.bounds solves the issue for me in conjunction with the rest of the code! Instead of customViewOutlet.bounds you should use customViewOutlet.layer.bounds

Comment: When changing the videoGravity to AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill the camera looks zoomed in. Could you please tell how to acheive without doing this? (Just like snapchat does)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the best way to go about this, but what worked for me was setting it to the screen size frame. So in that case it would be:

```
self.previewLayer.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
```

Hope this helps